# If a value in a json array returns null, how to return the next non-null json value?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

Currently I'm trying to return values from JSON data but am running into an issue where one of the values is returning null thereby causing my app to crash.

This is what the json looks like:

```
  "results": [
    {
      "genre_ids": [
        99
      ],
      "id": 440108,
      "poster_path": null, //The value that's causing incredible headaches!
    },
    {

      "genre_ids": [
        99,
        10402
      ],
      "id": 391698,
      "poster_path": "/uv7syi4vRyjvWoB8qExbqnbuCu5.jpg",//The value trying to get!
    },

]
```

I'm using the json object mapper [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) which has been good to this point. Here is how I have my objects set up:

```
public struct ResultsGenrePosters: Decodable {

  public let results :  [GenrePosters]?

  public init?(json: JSON) {
    results = "results" <~~ json
  }
}

public struct GenrePosters: Decodable, Equatable{

  public let poster : String

  public init? (json: JSON) {

    guard let poster: String = "poster_path" <~~ json
      else {return nil}
    self.poster = poster
  }
  public static func ==(lhs: GenrePosters, rhs: GenrePosters) -> Bool {
    return lhs.poster == rhs.poster
  }


  static func updateGenrePoster(genreID: NSNumber, urlExtension: String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ details: [String]) -> Void){

    let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager

    nm.getJSONData(type:"genre/\(genreID)", urlExtension: urlExtension, completion: {
      data in

      if let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONData(data)
      {
        guard let genrePosters = ResultsGenrePosters(json: jsonDictionary)

          else {
            print("Error initializing object")
            return
        }

        guard let posters = genrePosters.results

          else {
            print("No poster exists for genre: \(genreID)")// This keeps on triggering when the null object is hit, this is where it would be good to move to the next array to get that value
            return
        }

        let postersArray = posters.map {$0.poster}// converts custom object "GenrePosters" to String(poster value)
        completionHandler(postersArray)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check that variable using ??. Ex var strData = nil starData = strData ?? ""

Answer (score 0):

```
    guard let poster: String = "poster_path" <~~ json
```

should be

```
guard let poster = ("poster_path" <~~ json) as? String
```

(Of course you are using a library that I know nothing about, so the library could be crashing. JSONSerialization is your friend. It works. Everyone knows what it does).

Answer (score 0):

```
    for data in results as! [Dictionary<String,AnyObjects>]{
    var value1 = data["key"] as? String
    if value1 == nil{value1 = ""}else{}
    }
    }
    That was just a simple logic but completely work for me all the time. :)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular 
[How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). please add some text that explains what the code does and why it solves the problem.